# Is Event Tracking in Google Analytics associated with built-in metrics?

Tags: join, google-analytics, metrics, event-tracking

In Google Analytics (GA) I am working with Event Tracking and would like to do queries on Events, *joining* the with associated metrics such as `Page`, `Source`, etc. Within GA, Is an Event associated or related to these metrics or are they completely independent? This article ([Google Analytics Event Tracking by Page](http://blog.shufflepoint.com/2011/05/google-analytics-event-tracking-by-page.html)) seems to suggest that they are related, but wanted to verify.

Answer (score 0):

They are.

You can build custom reports that drill down from source to event categories and then actions and labels. Or custom reports that drill down from pages to events or the other way around.

Comment: Eduardo, thanks. When I drill down from pages and create an advanced segment with Event Category = A and Event Action = B and Event Label = C, the Total Events show up as the same for several combinations of Category, Action, and Label. I was told that event is associated with the Page, but category/action/label granularity is not associated with the Page. Thoughts?

Comment: Segments act on the visit. so when you create a segment for a specific event you get all visits that fired that specific page at least once during the visit. So you'll see all the pages they saw on the report, not only the one that fired the event. You probably want to create a custom report to drill down from pages to events. eg: http://goo.gl/MNoo1